# EditText doesn't keep the text entered, ie it deletes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a list of items as follows:

```js
 private void getProducts() {
        List<Product> listProducts = Product.getListProduct(true);
        if (listProducts != null && listProducts.size() > 0) {
            ProductAdapter m_adapterProduct = new ProductAdapter(this, listProducts);
            mlvwProducts.setAdapter(m_adapterProduct);
        }
    }
```

The ProductAdapter class is as follows:

```js
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Product> mdata;


    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> mdata) {
        super(context, R.layout.act_item_product_adapter, mdata);
        this.context = context;
        this.mdata = mdata;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.act_item_product_adapter,null);
        TextView m_product_name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_product_nameProduct);
        TextView m_product_cost = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_product_cost);
        TextView m_product_stock = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_product_stock);
        EditText m_product_amount = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_product_amount);
        ImageView m_product_photo = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_product_photo);



        m_product_name.setText(datos.get(position).getNombreProducto());
        m_product_cost.setText(" Cost: " + String.format("%.2f",mdata.get(position).getCostSold()));
        m_product_stock.setText(" Stock: " + Integer.toString(mdata.get(position).getStock()));
        //m_product_amout.setText("0");

        if (datos.get(position).getimagenProduct() != null){
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(mdata.get(position).getimagenProduct(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            m_product_photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length));
        }


        return  item;
    }
}
```

Everything works very well, I can retrieve the information of the products and display them in the list, but when in the EditText (m_product_amount) I enter a value and clicking another object of the activity, the number entered is deleted and remains at 0 that was The default number that is in the layout.

What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome

Thanks

============= Question updates ===============

act_item_product_adapter.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_product_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:cropToPadding="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/adapter_product_photo"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapter_product_nameProducto"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "37dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Name of product"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width= "170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adapter_product_photo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adapter_product_photo">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapter_product_cost"
            android:layout_width = "170dp"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="cost"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapter_product_stock"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="stock"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Amount"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/adapter_product_amount"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you post your layout(s). I suggest you use a RecyclerView.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question with the layout. Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you are retrieving what you entered in the `EditText` field...

Comment: That is the only element that doesn't recover. It is a list of products that are stored in a database. From that list I want the user to enter in the EditText the amount that will be desired by each item in the whole list for an order.

Comment: I think the problem is that the only way to add information to the elements of an ArrayAdpater is with public View getView, after that I think it is no longer possible. Or maybe again creating the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect ListView doesn't display multiple items, it is a single item in which it displays temporary information (a few milliseconds) on the objects it contains and then displays the next item that is the same but with other values.

It is for this reason that when pointing to another part the information is deleted and the one that was assigned in public View getView.

Then I create an array of type string for the value of EditText according to the number of the item as follows:

```js
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Producto> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Product> mdata;

    private EditText m_product_amount;
    private String[] m_amounts;
    
    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> mdata) {
       super(context, R.layout.act_item_product_adapter, mdata);
       this.context = context;
        this.mdata = mdata;
        m_amounts = new String[mdata.size()];

    }

    ...
 }
```

Then I initialize the editText with the values contained in the array as follows:

```js
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.act_item_product_adapter,null);
        
        ....


        if (null != m_amounts[position]) m_product_amount.setText(m_amounts[position]);


        ....
        
        return item;
}
```

And finally to update the values of each element of the array I do the following:

```js
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    ....
    
    
    
    
    m_product_amount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.adapter_product_amount:{
                        if (false == hasFocus && m_product_amount.getText().length() > 0) {
                            m_amounts[position] = m_product_amount.getText().toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    
    ...
    
    return item;
    
 }
```